# How are Hurricane Hunter planes able to withstand G's as high as 6-7 G in turbulence if the plane is only rated for G loads much lower than that?

Tags: turbulence

I found some conflicting reports on the G limit of the WP-3 Orion, but most sources say the G limit is 2.5 or 3 positive G, which would bring the ultimate load up to 3.7-4.5 G (as there is a 50% safety factor). Similar to the ultimate G loading on today's airliners. The WP-3 Orion is a modernized version of a commercial airliner called the Lockheed Electra. According to the Wikipedia article on the WP-3 Orion, they are not specially strengthened for flying into hurricanes.

There are reports of the WP-3 Orion experiencing G loadings well beyond the ultimate load with little to no damage during turbulence when it penetrated the eyewall, why is this?

https://noaahrd.wordpress.com/2014/09/15/25th-anniversary-of-a-hairy-hop-into-hurricane-hugo/

https://slate.com/technology/2014/08/interview-with-rookie-hurricane-hunter-joseph-patton.html

Comment: I am guessing it is because the aircraft are not operating at their max gross weight. Max G loads are for max weights. A lightly loaded aircraft can safely exceed the Max G load.

Comment: On top of that are vary large safety factors in the structural calcs, so a structure calculated for the normal load limits may be actually good for 3-4 Gs before anything bends beyond yield.  That plus the bulk of the load being fuel in the wings minimizes the ultimate bending on the wing roots and makes it good for much more.  I know of a CRJ that was subjected to something like nearly 4 Gs negative after a test mishap incident, and the plane wasn't permanently bent and was later delivered to the customer.  What saved it was having an empty cabin at the time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/43587/is-the-aircraft-used-by-noaa-specially-modified

Comment: @JuanJimenez, not a duplicate; that Q/A does not seem to discuss G loading anywhere.

Comment: @JanHudec That Q/A addresses the same core question posed here, why the aircraft is so sturdy.